# Redirect whole website to an URL with htaccess file

Tags: asp.net, .htaccess, redirect

I have a website with let us say 100 different URLS like:

```
http:/www.example.com/1.aspx
http:/www.example.com/2.aspx
...
...
http:/www.example.com/100.aspx
```

Now I want to redirect all of those URLs to:

```
http:/www.example.com
```

I am trying to do this with the: "htaccess.txt" file like below which is my "htaccess.txt" file but nothing happens/redirects. Am I doing this wrong?

Redirect code does not work?:

```
Redirect 301 / http://example.com
```

**htaccess.txt**

```
//Rewrite to www
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 / http://website.co
//Redirect 301 /abc/ http:/www.website.co/abc/1vv-contact.aspx


//Prevent viewing of .htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

//Prevent directory listings
Options All -Indexes
```

Comment: You are using the wrong directive for this to begin with - `Redirect` matches a path _prefix_, and _appends_ everything past that, to the target URL again. You need to do this using a RewriteRule.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteEngine on
> Redirect 301 / http://website.co
> ```

This mod_alias `Redirect` simply redirects to itself, so will result in a redirect loop. But you say "nothing happens"! The file needs to be called `.htaccess`, not `htaccess.txt` as you've stated throughout your question!

(Also `RewriteEngine` is to do with mod_rewrite - the two are unrelated.)

Assuming the URLs are all numeric (as in your example) then try something like the following instead:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/\d+\.aspx$ /
```

You'll need to clear your browser cache before testing.

> with the: "htaccess.txt" file like below which is my "htaccess.txt" file but nothing happens

You've referenced "htaccess.txt" throughout your question, but this should be called `.htaccess` not `htaccess.txt`. Otherwise, this won't do anything!